# How to implement move constructor and move assignment operator with inheritance(abstract base class)

Tags: c++

[The error message in Visual Studio I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHZhG.png)
I am learning c++ and wanted to test stuff.
I created an account hierarchy with Account (as abstract base class) and JointAccount (which has public inheritance from Account).
But I can't figure out how to implement copy constructor and copy assignment operator for JointAccount.
I tried a few things but it didn't work. I searched but there is no clear explanation.

```
class Account : public Printable
{
protected:
    std::string* name;
    double balance;

public:
    Account(std::string name, double balance);
    Account(const Account& source);
    Account(Account&& source);
    virtual ~Account();
    Account& operator=(const Account& rhs);
    Account& operator=(Account&& rhs);
    .
    .
    .
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override = 0;
};
```

```
Account::Account(Account&& source)
    :   name{source.name}, balance{source.balance}
{
    source.name = nullptr;
}

Account& Account::operator=(Account&& rhs)
{
    this->name = rhs.name;
    this->balance = rhs.balance;
    rhs.name = nullptr;
    return *this;
}
```

```
class JointAccount final : public Account
{
private:
    std::string* secondName;
public:
    JointAccount(std::string name, double balance, std::string secondName);
    JointAccount(const JointAccount& source);
    JointAccount(JointAccount&& source);
    virtual ~JointAccount();
    JointAccount& operator=(const JointAccount& rhs);
    JointAccount& operator=(JointAccount&& rhs);
    .
    .
    .
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override;
};
```

```
I tried this but it does not work as Account is Abstract VVV

JointAccount::JointAccount(JointAccount&& source)
    :   Account{source}, secondName{source.secondName}
{
    ?
}

And as I can't figure out the move constructor, I also can't figure 
out how to do the move assignment operator VVV

JointAccount& JointAccount::operator=(JointAccount&& rhs)
{
    ?
}
```

Comment: As a point of style (which is an opinion -- take it under advisement), if you use `override` (which I recommend), no need to also use the redundant `virtual`.

Comment: `std::string* name;` do you really want pointer here?

Comment: default implementation seems fine BTW (`= default`)

Comment: `JointAccount::JointAccount(JointAccount&& source) : Account{std::move(source)}` should do it, I think.

Comment: @Eljay I know its redundant and not required. But actually someone else who has been an instructor for lot of the big companies advised me to do so as a good practice. Cos if there are a lot of levels of inheritance in your project and someone is using your project ( library, engine, etc) then he will not have to go to the base class to see if its virtual or not.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am just practicing various important stuff so as to clear my concepts. So the (std::string* name) is to understand the move constructor and move assignment operator. That's why the (double balance) is not a pointer. I wanted to have both so has to get comfortable with primitive and pointer implementations.  I didn't want to start on big projects with lots of class members only to get stuck. Also (= default) for what? the destructor?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah I tried it before, but it doesn't compile. Error msg: Object of abstract class type "Account" is not allowed. Since print is a pure virtual function in the Account class.

Comment: If you use `override`, then it has to be virtual and overriding.  No need to go to the base class.  This advice comes from Sean Parent as best practice with modern C++.  Sean is on the C++ standards committee.

Comment: [Compiles for me](https://rextester.com/YIQT26401). To the extent there is a problem, it lies in the code you haven't shown. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @Eljay Yeah that does make a lot of sense. Thanks a lot. I'll change my style. :D

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah after seeing your and Carter12s 's msg, I wrote the complete code and it compiled in coliru https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5db8b80df9b30b5 and then it even compiled in VS but I was still getting a red line and error msg that I told you about before in VS even after successful build. I have added the link to that image in the first line of my original question. Could you please tell me why its happening. And I taught that red line meant error so I didn't write ahead and got stuck trying to find the solution to the supposed error.

Comment: Thank you for posting the code.  Here are my suggestions: 1) turn on compiler warnings and fix them, 2) do not use `string*` as a member field, because that's bizarre (since string is already a smart object that manages its resources), 3) move constructor and move assignment operator should be `noexcept`, 4) you should be able to use the `= default` for move constructor and move assignment operator assuming the classes are (in my opinion) sane, and if they are not sane they ought not have move ctor and move=.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for reviewing my code and giving suggestions. I really appreciate it. I'll make sure to use noexcept. But I didn't get the 4th point. What does classes being sane mean? I searched for it but couldn't find anything good. Also I posted a link of an image of VisualSudio showing me red underlined supposed error but then successfully building the solution (link is 1st line of my original question). Thats the reason why I got stuck. Could you please tell me why it was showing the red line, I can't figure it out. And is there anyway I can turn it off ( ie If I should ).

Comment: My use of "sane" here means "the class does not itself micromanage its member variables", where "micromanage" means the class is using member variables which do not self-manage themselves.  (If they do not self-manage themselves, you cannot use `= default`.)

Comment: @Eljay K thanks. understood. Do you know why VS was giving me that red line. When I worked with python on PyCharm, if there was a red underline, that meant it was an error and wouldn't compile. But with c++ in VS it seems more like a its using redline (instead of grey) for warnings. Anyways, I appreciate all the time you spent to solve my issue and give me suggestions. Also saw your profile, its amazing you know so much about so many languages. Was inspiring.

Comment: I'm using a text editor and a command line compiler.  I do not know why VS is giving you the red line.  Thank you for the compliment!  I like learning lots of programming languages, but I've discovered that I'm in a small minority.  C++ is a very challenging language because it is not a nanny language, and it has evolved with difficulty because of a strong motive for backwards compatibility, and it is a complex language with subtly and nuance, and some unfortunate syntax, giving it a steep learning curve.

Comment: intellisense has false positives to detect errors (it has to do it quickly than true compiler, and possibly during edition)...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of what I think you are attempting to do that compiles correctly: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a5b64904f262b5a

I suspect that your problem is failing to define functions that you are declaring as virtual. The solution is to ensure that all virtual methods that are not pure are defined. Note that a destructor must be defined even if it is declared pure-virtual.

The basic structure of what you are attempting seems valid, so your issue appears to lie elsewhere in your implementation.

Comment: Actually, I have defined all the non pure virtual functions in the .cpp file.
Its only for the sake of the question not getting too long, that I decided to not put it here.
They all work just fine.
Its just the move constructor and move copy assignment operator that I can't figure out.
How did your code complie? The compiler gives me an error msg: Object of abstract class type "Account" is not allowed. Since print in Account class is pure virtual function. So, it should give you compile error at "line 54" of your code.

Comment: Yeah after seeing your and IgorTandetnik 's msg, I wrote the complete code and it compiled in coliru https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5db8b80df9b30b5 and then it even compiled in VS but I was still getting a red line and error msg that I told you about before in VS even after successful build. I have added the link to that image in the first line of my original question. Could you please tell me why its happening. And I taught that red line meant error so I didn't write ahead and got stuck trying to find the solution to the supposed error.